# displayport + 3.5mm audio to HDMI?

Tags: audio, hdmi, thinkpad, displayport

I have a Lenovo W500 and apparently, the graphics card (ati radeon) doesn't support audio output through the display port. But, connecting separately from the headphones to the RCA inputs in the TV doesn't work either. I searched for a DisplayPort->HDMI adapter that also supports a 3.5mm audio jack, but could not find one. I want to use the DisplayPort output and not VGA, to get better resolution. So, what are my options ?

Comment: What resolution are you trying to run?

Comment: 720p or 1080p..

Comment: [Relevant Lenovo statement](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/W-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/Displayport-to-HDMI-with-audio/td-p/68575/page/23#lineardisplaymessageviewwrapper_6).

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but at those resolutions, you're not going to see much difference with VGA vs. DisplayPort or HDMI.